# Is it possible to use wildcards in database values rather than in the input variable?

Tags: sql

I have a simplified example using license plates stored in a single column table. Let's assume I have the table below, where some of the values are stored with a wildcard: * to denote multiple characters or ? to denote one character. In this situation, would it be possible to run sort of a reverse LIKE query?

**Name**
507KL?
2RCS20
8HD7AC
HA04*
HA0401

For example, let's assume I receive a license plate number HA0422. I would like to write a query that matches on the 4th row in my table. Is this possible with just SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `like` parameters in any order you want -- the pattern can come from a column.  However, `*` is not  wildcard.  `%` is.  And `?` presumably means `_`.  So:

```
where 'HA0422' like replace(replace(name, '*', '%'), '?', '_')
```

Comment: Same for '_' instead of '?'